# How to plot 500 points in a second in highchart?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, jquery, highcharts

We are supposed to plot 500 points every second from ajax request which we get it from WCF service(hosted in amazon cloud).
We are using highchart, but its very slow.

Is there any solution ? or any other graph control which we can use it in our case so that performnace is efficient

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: false,//Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                renderTo: 'Chart',
                events: {
                    load: function () {


                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                max: ((new Date()).getTime()) + 50 * 10000
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Data',
                    min: 50,
                    max: 500
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#FFFF00'

                }]
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {

            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {

                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Chart',

                color: '#335de8',

                //data: []
                data: (function () {
                    //generate an array of random data
                    var data = [];
                    var data = [],
                                    time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;
                    for (i = 1; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: null
                        });
                    }

                    return data;

                })()
            }]

        });

        chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(-200, 500);

           UpdateChart();

        function UpdateChart() {
        var Chrt = chart.series[0];
         setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getChartData/',
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (result) {
          for (var tmpJ = 0; tmpJ < result.length; tmpJ++) {

         Chrt.addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), eval(result[tmpJ])], true, false);
                                 Chrt.redraw(false);
         }
       });
        }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: How your code looks like? I advice to add point, but animate/redraw only on last.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan, i have added code

Comment: this is off topic to your question, but using `setInterval` in that matter might get your sequence out of order, not sure if that is something you care about, one of solving is to trigger the request only if done receiving the previous one, a network congestion can be much higher than the allotted 1 second per request

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line

```
Chrt.addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), eval(result[tmpJ])], true, false);
```

with

```
 if(tmpJ==result.length-1){
        Chrt.addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), eval(result[tmpJ])], false, false);
 } else {
        Chrt.addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), eval(result[tmpJ])], true, false);
 }
```